# Romans and Ancient Greek language

Tags: classical-latin, greek, word-comparison, koine-greek, linguistics

Is there evidence in the inscriptions, that Romans have realised, that Hellenic languages are very close to theirs own language!? It seems to be that the distinguish was applied to the Etruscan language. But I heard nothing about Greek.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Also related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/what-did-the-greeks-and-romans-believe-about-language-relationships

Comment: Thanks to you too!

Comment: @TrmIntrs2 Do you think the question Asteroides links to answers your question fully? If it does, we can mark this question as a duplicate of it. If it doesn't, can you edit your question to specify what aspect is missing there? Adding the link given by TKR to the question would also be helpful for building context if you find it relevant.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmarvirta Yes. As can I see there nothing more to say about this theme. So my question able to be tagged as 'doublet'. Thanks!